# Subscribe() returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable, subscribe

I'm not being able to use the result from subscribe() outside of subscribe(), console.log always returns undefined. My assumption is that it has something to do with the async thing but I don't know a workaround to make this work. Should I use promise instead?

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    textt: String;

    constructor(private tstService: MyComponentService) { this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.data) }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.tstService.getTstWithObservable()
        .map(result => result.map(i => i.user.data))
        .subscribe(
           res => { this.textt = res[0].title; }
       );
    }

    data = [
        {
          title: this.textt,
          sdate: '01/04/1990',
          edate: '30/09/1990',
        },
      ];

    source: LocalDataSource;
}
```

Comment: You would have to do the processing inside of the `subscribe` callback. Is that a problem?

Comment: I've tried that too, but data[] never gets populated inside of subscribe

Comment: Please show us how you tried to do it.

Comment: _"I've tried that too,"_ How?

Comment: I mean, if I compile the code like I've show you in the OP the table gets populated with data[], I've tried moving data[] after this.textt = res[0].title; and inside ngOnInit. That didn't work, table starts empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the problem is that the `subscribe` works asynchronous.
The `data.title` isn't set at the creation, because `this.textt` is not set at the time the component is created and it will be set at another (not known) time.

To update your `data` attribute. You can create it inside the subscription or you simply set the `title` inside it.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tstService.getTstWithObservable()
    .map(result => result.map(i => i.user.data))
    .subscribe(
       res => { 
           this.textt = res[0].title; 
           this.data.title = this.textt;
       }
   );
}
```

Comment: does this work on the first load of the page?